# The usage of 当たり前 as subject

Tags: grammar, usage, particle-が

As far as I know, 当たり前 is an adverb. How come in the following instances it's used as the subject?

> あの日見た夕日　あの日見た花火　いつでも君がいたね
> **当たり前が**幸せと知った ー「合唱曲・群青」

> 君がここにいなくなって　**当たり前が**いなくなって ー「君の抜け殻」

I am a little puzzled by this usage of 当たり前 as the subject. The が cannot be the contrast-particle が because that doesn't make sense either(plus one needs to say XXだが and not XXが for 名詞 and 形容動詞). I think it must be the subject-marker が. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BD%93%E3%82%8A%E5%89%8D/

当たり前 works as a noun as you can see from the 「名・形動」 listing. The relevant definition is 2 here, I believe. They learned their 'normality', 'what they took for granted' (something like that) was happiness, and then 'it' (implied to be 君 with the verb choice **い**なくなって) disappeared.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like it's equivalent to the English "the norm"